# Is there a light-weight alternative to Boost for a Date/Time library in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, datetime, date, boost

I am looking for a cross-platform library to parse and output textual date/times to and from both positive and negative 64 bit timestamps.

Does such a library exist? Boost has a large amount of overhead that I would rather not include as well as templating, etc. Is there a more light-weight alternative available?

Comment: It's possible to only use parts of the Boost library without relying on the whole thing. I'd suggest that.

Comment: Does everyone who develops in c++ just universally rely on boost? I feel like there is a lack of diversity.

Comment: Not at all. But diversity isn't necessarily a great thing, especially when you have access to such a widely tried and tested library.

Comment: `boost::posix_time::ptime` is just a wrapper around `struct timeval` on unix platforms. There's nothing heavyweight about it. Don't assume that because a class has a rich API that it has a large footprint.

Comment: As I mentioned, I would really like to have both windows and unix compatibility. Also, that is still 32 bit to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: It is compatible with both Windows and Unix. I mentioned Unix because that is the platform I was working on when I decided to dig down `boost::posix_time::ptime` to see how lightweight it really is.

Comment: `struct timeval` uses `time_t` for seconds since the epoch, which is 64-bit on 64-bit Linux (IIRC). There's a bug report about a 2038 problem with regards to Boost.Date_Time: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4543

Comment: The whole point of boost is to provide a single proving ground for things that can potentially be brought into the standard. Thus we only have one shared_ptr implementation that works really well rather than a hundred crappy ones.

Comment: You only incur the overhead of the parts you use. So there really is no overhead in using boost. The advantage is you get stuff that is highly tested.

Comment: Just to let you know, almost all modern C++ uses templates. You might want to avoid C++ altogether if you don't like templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could find to suit my needs is found here:

http://www.2038bug.com/pivotal_gmtime_r.c.html

After eliminating the localtime functions, this builds in VC++ and allows for 64 bit timestamps, both positive and negative. I have yet to test strftime with dates past 2038, but for now this will fix my issue.

Comment: Unfortunately without using one of the more standard license agreements this becomes unusable by most people.

Comment: @LokiAstari: It's an "old BSD license", which is a bit obnoxious but fairly standard.